# base64 image not decoding php

Tags: php, html

I have an image in HTML5 canvas which is taken from webcam's live stream. When I get a frame as snapshot and save it in canvas I do this

```
var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
dom.write('<form method="post" action="upload.php"><input type="myImage" value="'+myImage+'" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>')
```

and in upload.php I do this

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$img= $_GET["myImage"];
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.$img.'" />';
```

doing this I get a popup window when page is loaded and when the form is submitted, it give me

```
data:image/png;base64,"VERY HUGE STRING"
```

I want to get it as an image. Please Help

Comment: `type="myImage"` you probably mean `name=myImage`.

Comment: I changed `type` to `name` but no difference. It give me very long string in a text box followed by a submit button, in popup window

Comment: you're submitting via POST, but retrieving from $_GET. that's not going to work...

Comment: changed to `_POST` but no difference :(

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `header` suggests you want to output the actual PNG image as the response to the request. However, you then write out an HTML tag, which is not valid in a PNG file.

If you want to write out the PNG image itself, presuming `$img` contains a valid PNG-format image, you can decode the base64 with the [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function:

```
echo base64_decode($img);
```

If you want to show the image on an HTML page, change your `header` call to read `Content-Type: text/html`.

Comment: I want to save it in a folder, and how do I know the PNG image is valid or not. Another problem I think is the submit button, the decoded string is visible in text box followed by submit button. How do I get rid of that

Comment: To get rid of the text box, set your `<input>` to have `type="hidden"`.

Comment: To clarify, is the purpose of `upload.php` to take the image data POSTed to it by the form and save it to a file?

Comment: If the purpose is to show the image to the user to allow them to save it themselves, change your `header` line as detailed and then follow @jabbink's answer: simply use `'src="' . $img . '"`, without the extra `data:image/`, etc.

Comment: Yes the purpose of `upload.php` is to take image and store it to file

Comment: To store it as a file on the server, you would need to extract the base64 data from the string (e.g. `$data = substr($img, 22)`) and then use `fopen` and friends to save it. To save it to the client's machine, keep the `Content-Type: image/png`, set `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="snap.png"')` to have the browser download it instead of displaying it, and just `echo $data`.

Answer (score 2):

canvas.toDataURL() already includes the `data:image/***;base64,` part, so remove it from your output.